# error to parse value from membership provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i try to make login system with membership provider and repository class
when i try to pass value from my membership class to my  repository class, the value can be pass..

whats wrong with my code??

```
namespace XNet.Services
{
    public class MembershipProviderService:IMembershipProviderService
    {
        IEntityRepository<User> _UserRepository;

        public MembershipProviderService(IEntityRepository<User> _UserRepository)
        {
            this._UserRepository = _UserRepository;
        }
        public MembershipProviderService()
        {

        }
        public User GetDataLogin(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            //List<User> GetData = _UserRepository.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.UserName == UserName && x.UserPassword == Password).ToList();
            var x = (from d in _UserRepository.All()
                     where d.UserName == UserName && d.UserPassword == Password
                     select d).FirstOrDefault();
            return x;
        }

    }
}
```

XnetMembership

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Security;
using XNet.Interfaces;
using XNet.Repository.Interfaces;
using XNet.Repository.Model;
using XNet.Services;
using Ninject;

namespace XNet.Security
{
    public class XNetMembership : MembershipProvider
    {
        [Inject]
        public IMembershipProviderService _membershipProviderService { get; set; }
        //private readonly IMembershipProviderService _membershipProviderService;

        //public XNetMembership()
        //{

        //}

        //public XNetMembership(IMembershipProviderService membershipProviderService)
        //{
        //    _membershipProviderService = membershipProviderService;
        //}



        public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool EnablePasswordReset
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override bool EnablePasswordRetrieval
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override int GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string GetPassword(string username, string answer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override int PasswordAttemptWindow
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override MembershipPasswordFormat PasswordFormat
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override bool RequiresUniqueEmail
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override string ResetPassword(string username, string answer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool UnlockUser(string userName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {

            var x = _membershipProviderService.GetDataLogin(username, password);
            return true;
            //if (x.Count() > 0)
            //{
            //    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
            //    return true;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    return false;
            //}
        }

    }
}
```

IXNetMembershipService

```
namespace XNet.Interfaces
{
    public interface IMembershipProviderService
    {
        User GetDataLogin(string UserName, string Password);
    }
}
```

my controller

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User user)
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(user.UserName, user.UserPassword))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(user);
}
```

Global asx

```
namespace XNet.WebUI.Hotel
{

    public class NinjectDenpendencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IResolutionRoot _resolutionRoot;

        public NinjectDenpendencyResolver(IResolutionRoot kernel)
        {
            _resolutionRoot = kernel;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _resolutionRoot.TryGet(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _resolutionRoot.GetAll(serviceType);
        }

    }

    internal class MyNinjectModules : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IMembershipProviderService>()
                .To<MembershipProviderService>();
        }
    }


    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        private IKernel _kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyNinjectModules());

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            _kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider);
        }
    }
}
```

NinjectWebCommon

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(XNet.WebUI.Hotel.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(XNet.WebUI.Hotel.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace XNet.WebUI.Hotel.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;
    using XNet.Services;
    using XNet.Interfaces;
    using XNet.Repository;
    using XNet.Repository.Interfaces;
    using XNet.Repository.Model;
    using XNet.Repository.Repositories;
    using XNet.Pipelines;
    using System.Web.Security;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {

            EF_RepoRegistration.RegisterRepository(kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHotelService>().To<HotelService>().InRequestScope();
            //kernel.Bind<IFacilityService>().To<FacilityService>().InRequestScope();
            //kernel.Bind<IHotelFacilityService>().To<HotelFacilityService>().InRequestScope();
            //kernel.Bind<IHotelRoomFacilityService>().To<HotelRoomFacilityService>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IRoomTypeService>().To<RoomTypeService>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IRoomFacilityService>().To<RoomFacilityService>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IRoomTypePipeline>().To<RoomTypePipeline>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IAccountService>().To<AccountService>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IMembershipProviderService>().To<MembershipProviderService>().InRequestScope();

        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear. What is your specific error? You say "when i try to pass value from my membership class to my repository class, the value can be pass." .... if the value can be passed then what is the issue?

Comment: my error is System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. can you tell me why?

Comment: Post the full stack trace, they generally point you to the line of code the error occurs. Also have you debugged? A random guess is that your using some sort of dependency injection and your IMembershipProviderService is not being injected properly.

Comment: i already post my full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a NullReferenceException in ValidateUser I would guess that _membershipProviderService is null.  Can you verify?  If so, I would guess that the issue is that the default constructor does not instantiate _membershipProviderService.

You would need something like this:

```
public XNetMembership() : 
   this(new XNetMembershipProvider())
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this line is failing:

```
var x = _membershipProviderService.GetDataLogin(username, password);
```

Put a break point right here, and see what the value is for _membershipProviderService. Is it null? That's your problem.

It looks like your problem is Ninject related from your comments.

Ninject shouldn't be limited to only your controllers. If you have a service that is dependent on a repository, why not use Ninject there as well? It works the exact same as the controller. Then you can easily test.

To resolve this issue you need to do the same thing with your membership provider to wire up the dependency as you did your controller. I'm not familiar with Ninject, but maybe you are missing a binding in some config file, or an attribute?

Something like:

```
kernel.Bind<IMembershipProviderService >().To<MyAwesomeMembershipProviderService>();
```

Comment: yes, value is null.., but i try to learn and find my mistake, i dont understand why the value is null

Comment: Are you using Dependency Injection?

Comment: Did you wire up some implementation to be injected in the place of IMembershipProviderService ?

Comment: in IMembershipProvider, i just use this code     public interface IMembershipProviderService
    {
        List<string> GetDataLogin(string UserName, string Password);
    }

Comment: Ninject is responsible for "making _membershipProviderService" not null. It passes in an implementation of your interface. Something is not working right with Ninject. Please edit your original post with the relevant Ninject configurations.

Comment: i usually using ninject to my controller, i never use ninject to inject other class, could you tell me,  how ninject work in other class

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code and configuration for ninject

Comment: Sorry I'm afraid I cannot help any further. Your setup looks OK to me although I have not used Ninject in years, I use Unity and it just works for me. Looks like Ninject has a LOT more setup than Unity.

Comment: its ok jack.. finally i delete my membership provider and i make my own membership with new class and service.. thanks for your help jack